# Referencing a Changing CSS ID

Tags: css, microstrategy

I should preface this by saying I'm a complete beginner in the world of editing CSS, so I apologize if this is very simple. I've been editing reports I've built in [MicroStrategy](http://www.microstrategy.com/us) 9.4, but we recently upgraded to 10.1. Before the upgrade, I was able to look at lines of the HTML, such as

```
<div ty="dsec" id="K1" scriptclass="mstrDocSectionImpl" name="K1" class="mstrDocSection">
```

and make minor edits. An example would be something like

```
<style>
    #K1{
        height:130px;
    }
</style>
```

to just make a simple height change for a section. I could paste that Style change into an HTML container, which would effect the report at run time. I believe the `K1` refers to an ID. However, after the upgrade, the line has been changed to

```
<div id="*lK3*kK1*x1*t1454966440926" k="K1" class="mstrmojo-DocSection" style="">
```

where `id="..."` changes each time I run it. Since it changes, I do not know of a reliable way to edit that section. The `k="K1"` does not change, but I'm not sure how to reference this. Any insight you can provide into this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
[k="K1"] {
  height: 150px;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tvs1a9u/)

Although this might be a bit more work it looks like the new ID (`id=""`) might be partially static. That is, the asterisks appear to be separators of some kind. If so, you could optionally select on a portion of that ID string that doesn't change. In my example below I'm assuming that data between the second and third asterisk in `*lK3*kK1*x1*t1454966440926` doesn't change. If so you could select on that portion of the string.

```css
[id*="kK1"] {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tvs1a9u/1)

Comment: You are correct that the `kK1` section appears to be static, but neither of these work. It's possible (though it would be a **huge** disappointment) that they have deprecated some of these features. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Who depreciated what features? The solutions above work as demonstrated in the provided JSFiddles. If you're not seeing any changes it's going to be that the [specificity](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20specificity) of the selector is high enough.

Comment: It could be that MicroStrategy removed the ability to edit reporting. It would be pretty shocking though, so I'll dig around some more. I have no doubt that your solution would work in general, but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the specificity of the selector? Right now the specificity of the selectors above is `0010` (pretty low). Is there an outer element that has a static ID on it that you can add to your selector to increase it's specificity? If so, you could do something like `#micro-strategy [k="K1"]` which has a specificity of `0110` which is higher than `[k="K1"]`, specificity of `0010`.

Comment: That did it, thank you! I'll have to play around with it, but that seems to be the problem.